# Check if directory can be opened and list its files

Tags: java, permissions, directory

I'm developing a shell in Java. This shell can execute the command `find 'regex'`. This command finds all the files which have a name that matches the `regex`, recursively. The method that finds the files is:

```
 public void findFile(String regExp, String dirName) {
    File dir = new File(dirName);

    if (dir.canRead() == false)
        return;

    File[] files = dir.listFiles();

    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile() == true)
            if (file.getName().matches(regExp) == true)
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (file.isDirectory() == true && file.canRead() == true) {
            findFile(regExp, file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

But this command fails if directory cannot be opened. For example, in `D:` partition, I have a hidden directory named `found.00` (this directory might belong to the system) and I cannot open this directory. When the method encounters this directory, it fails. How can I check if directory belongs to the system and cannot be opened?

Comment: It may not cover all cases of unopenable directories, but you could check for `File#isHidden()`.

Comment: Instead of using `file.isFile() == true`, just use `file.isFile()`. Or if you're trying to see if something is `false`: `dir.canRead() == false`, just use `!dir.canRead()`.

Comment: @Jeffrey: I know major enterprise (>60000 people) where if( bool == true ) is mandatory and if( b ) forbidden...

Comment: I know, I only want my code to be easily readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you use `file.canRead()` already I would say you could surround the complete content of method `findFile(String regExp, String dirName)` with a try-catch. You can then catch and log or also ignore the access error. Try the following one please.

```
public void findFile(final String regExp, final String dirName) {
   try {
      final File dir = new File(dirName);

      if (dir.canRead() == false) {
         return;
      }

      final File[] files = dir.listFiles();

      for (final File file : files) {
         if (file.isFile() && file.getName().matches(regExp)) {
               System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
         }
         if ((file.isDirectory()) && (file.canRead())) {
            findFile(regExp, file.getAbsolutePath());
         }
      }
   } catch (final IOException ignore) {
      System.out.println("No access to '"+dirName+"'.");
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the exception will interrupt the recursion?

Comment: I am not sure. What is the exact exception (and maybe stacktrace) when you try to open the dir?

Comment: The exception is: IOException.

Comment: Strange.When you are on Java 7 you could try java.nio.file.Path.